# How to attack this tiling puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, tiling

[The 1000 point problem on SRM 209, Div I]

At some stage, the problem reduces to the following:

Given blocks of three square units, like below, which can be rotated in any manner, how many ways are there to fill a rectangular block of given size.

```
| x | x |
| x |
```

For example, for a block of 3x4, there are 4 ways of arranging these blocks. I am looking for a way to attack this problem, and not the actual solution. How do I go about finding the number of ways. There are so many ways that it could happen, and I do not see overlapping sub problems for a DP approach either.

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: tiling is an np problem, so the only way would be to group the tiles into pairs and try every combination of the 3x2 blocks

Comment: That's an exact cover problem, and you can solve it with a zero-suppressed BDD without enumerating all solutions.

Comment: I get 22025514 for 8x9, is that correct?

Comment: @harold: sorry, I am not sure what the solution for 8x9 is.

Comment: Do you know any nontrivial results? And is my approach clear? I could explain it in a bit more detail if you'd like

Comment: Topcoder has editorials describing a solution for every problem. Did you check them?

Answer (score -1):

Without exception, every tiling of a pxq block of space with L-shaped tiles, will reduce to tiling with 2x3 blocks consisting pairs of your L-shaped tiled. I.e. the tiles are either in the form:

```
        xx      xx
        xy  or  yx  to form a vertical 2x3 block or
        yy      yy

        xyy       xxy
        xxy  or   xyy  to form a horizontal 3,2 block.
```

So you can already reduce your problem to a 'parquet'-tiling of a rectangle with 2x3 and 3x2 rectangles. Unless, of course, you are tiling an irregular  non-rectangular region - in which case you have to consider the L-shaped tiles individualy.

Comment: This is wrong, e.g. `0011 | 0221 | 3324 | 3544 | 6557 | 6677`.